# How to create a limited use Lubuntu custom desktop?

Tags: lubuntu, configuration, desktop-environments

I'm working on a project for a nonprofit cultural center.

I’m trying to develop a limited desktop using Lubuntu. The idea is to provide a basic desktop, maybe only four icons, Chrome, OpenOffice, Adobe reader, calculator and printing services and nothing else.

As part of their service to the community, they provide computers, printing and internet access. Currently in place are PCs running different versions of windows and MS Office which are problematic due to licensing, access to system settings, viruses and the like.

I’m trying to provide the center a machine that gives the patrons everything they need without allowing the users able to muddle with any OS features and provide a machine that requires as little administration as is possible.

So far, I’ve been able to comment out all menus and other desktop functionality.

The machine boots to a login prompt, and the Patron user I've setup simply presses the login button and they get the mini desktop. Logging off is done with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>backspace</kbd>, it works great except that I’ve been unable to find a way to remove the “desktop preferences” from the right click mouse menu or completely disable the desktop mouse menu, either solution would work.

In addition, can I disable the terminal session for this user?

Any advice or different approaches to creating such a mini session would be welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Was there a specific reason that you tagged this with version 12.04? Are you limited by hardware specs? If so, can you add those details to your question?

Comment: no specific reason, only because the form was requiring a tag and it rejected the others I chose. Thanks for reformatting my post, I'll make sure any in the future are paragraphed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get rid of it, since it's part of `PCmanFM` (Lubuntu's default desktop manager).

But you can replace it: right-click the desktop, then select **Desktop Preferences > Advanced** and tick **Show menus provided**.

This will use openbox's right-click menu.

You can then edit out any entries you don't want in:

```
/usr/share/lubuntu/openbox/menu.xml
```

By the way, to restore `pcmanfm`'s menu, you must run this command in a terminal:

```
 pcmanfm --desktop-pref
```